# Get a reference for a scala object in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, scala

I'm trying to access a scala object from MATLAB.

To get a reference to a scala object in java, you can use

```
ObjectName$.MODULE$
```

But in MATLAB `$`, like `#`, is an invalid character (I've always wondered why this is). Although accessing a field or method is not so bad

```
ObjectName.field
ObjectName.method
```

for some things it would be nice to be able to access the object itself. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is using wrapper written in java an option for you?

Comment: @om-nom-nom yes, but it's not ideal.